# Snowflake - getting 'Error parsing JSON' while using the Copy command from S3 to snowflake

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i'm trying to copy gz files from my S3 directory to Snowflake.

1. i created a table in snowflake (notice that the 'extra' field is defined as 'Variant')

```html
CREATE TABLE accesslog
(
 loghash VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
 logdatetime TIMESTAMP,
 ip VARCHAR(15),
 country VARCHAR(2),
 querystring VARCHAR(2000),
 version VARCHAR(15),
 partner INTEGER,
 name VARCHAR(100),
 countervalue DOUBLE PRECISION,
 username VARCHAR(50),
 gamesessionid VARCHAR(36),
 gameid INTEGER,
 ingameid INTEGER,
 machineuid VARCHAR(36),
 extra variant,
 ingame_window_name VARCHAR(2000),
 extension_id VARCHAR(50)
    
);
```

2. i used this copy command in snowflake:

```html
copy  INTO accesslog
 FROM s3://XXX
    pattern='.*cds_201911.*'
    CREDENTIALS = (
        aws_key_id='XXX',
        aws_secret_key='XXX')
    FILE_FORMAT=(
        error_on_column_count_mismatch=false
     FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'
        TYPE = CSV 
        COMPRESSION = GZIP
        FIELD_DELIMITER = '\t'
        )
        ON_ERROR =  CONTINUE
```

3. I run it, and got this result (i got many error lines, this is an example to one)
   [snowflake result](https://www.screencast.com/t/MgGygdflR)
   [snowflake result -more](https://www.screencast.com/t/MNSoTch9a7)

```html
a17589e44ae66ffb0a12360beab5ac12 2019-11-01 00:08:39 155.4.208.0 SE  0.136.0 3337 game_process_detected 0 OW_287d4ea0-4892-4814-b2a8-3a5703ae68f3 e9464ba4c9374275991f15e5ed7add13  765 19f030d4-f85f-4b85-9f12-6db9360d7fcc [{"Name":"file","Value":"wowvoiceproxy.exe"},{"Name":"folder","Value":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\World of Warcraft\\_retail_\\Utils\\WowVoiceProxy.exe"}]
```

can you please tell me what cause this error? 
thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing;

The `'Error parsing JSON'` is certainly related to the `extra variant` field.

The JSON looks fine, but there are potential problems with the backslashes `\`.
If you look at the successfully loaded lines, have the backslashes been removed?

This can (maybe) happen if you have `STAGE` settings involving escape characters.

The `\\Utils` substring in the Windows path value can then trigger a Unicode decode error, eg.
`Error parsing JSON: hex digit is expected in \U???????? escape sequence, pos 123`

**UPDATE:**
It turns out you have to turn off escape char processing by adding the following to the `FILE_FORMAT`:

```
ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD  = NONE
```

The alternative is to doublequote fields or to doubly escape backslash, eg. `C:\\\\Program Files`.

Comment: hey @Hans Henrik Eriksen
when i look at the  successfully loaded lines, some of the backslashes havn't been removed.
also, i'm not using STAGE for this copy process ( i pasted here the entire script that i'm using).

is there a way to load these rows (even if they contain backslashes ?)

Comment: UPDATE:  see answer above about `ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD`

Comment: Thank you  @Hans Henrik Eriksen ,
i will check it up!

Comment: I did test that it worked with the one line you supplied, but I could obviously not test the other lines.  If it doesn't, I would have gone for fully quoting at least the JSON fields, eg `"{""a"": ""\\path""}"`

Comment: Thanks a ton to both of you for saving me from having to find this myself!